# Toggle element with jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hello I have got a problem with a toggle of an element. 
No idea what I am doing wrong, here is an example for what I got.

```
<h3 class="klik">Optreden (plaats hier)</h3>
<p> - Datum gaat hier.</p>
<span>
    <p> Informatie over optreden hier </p>
</span>
<h3 class="klik">Optreden (plaats hier)</h3>
<p> - Datum gaat hier.</p>
<span>
    <p> Informatie over optreden hier </p>
</span>
```

As script I am using this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('span').hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $(".klik").click(function(){
    $(this).next("span").toggle("easing");
   });//hide antwoorden
  $("span").click(function(){
    $(this).hide ("easing");
   });
});
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Kind Regards,

Michael

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/   What exactly are you trying to do by passing 'easing' into the hide method?

Comment: why not just put everything in a simple $(document).ready(function()
{});

Comment: that's not how .next() works. this is a duplicate